# Появился странный значок после добавления ссылки на сайте

Tags: html, css

После добавления ссылки в кнопку, появился странный знак, его абсолютно никак нельзя убрать. Код предоставляю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CiLwaGlRw8&feature=emb_logo" target="_blank"><button class="youtube"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Видеоролик

Answer (score 1):

Данный знак появляется от стороннего расширения вашего браузера - например скачивания видео с Youtube и т п. Чтобы его убрать, отключите данное расширение в вашем браузере